# How to find cluster centers of Spark's StreamingKMeans?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

When I use Spark's KMeansModel class, I can easily access the centroids of my model's clusters using the `KMeansModel.clusterCenters()` function.

I wanted to use StreamingKMeans, but I noticed that it seems to lack a `clusterCenters()` function. Is there a way to obtain the centroids of my model's clusters in StreamingKMeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch KMeans, an estimator is trained once and produces a single transformer - the model which contains the `clusterCenters()` method. In StreamingKMeans, a model is continuously updated, so you need to use the `latestModel()` on the StreamingKMeans object.

```
val model = new StreamingKMeans()
      .setK(5)
      .setDecayFactor(1.0)
      .setRandomCenters(10, 0.0)
val latestModel = model.latestModel()
println(latestModel.clusterCenters)
```